# OJDBC code issue in Java Eclipse

Tags: java, jdbc

I have made a registration table reg1 and stored the values for every registered users from a HTML file. Now I have made a Log-In page in HTML where users can give their username and see the datas entered by them. I have made an user "bbb" and want to show his username only.So I made the general java code like follows:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    public class Check extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
    * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    */
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         String username=request.getParameter("username");
         try{
             Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
             String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE";
             Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"system","root");
             Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select uname from reg1");


            while(rs.next())    
                {

                String name=rs.getString("uname");
                if(name==username)
                {


                response.setContentType("text/html");
                PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
                pw.println("Your User name is:"+username);

            //  System.out.println(""+name);
                }



                    con.commit();

                }
             stmt.close();
    }


                catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


    }

   }
```

It is giving errors like `java.sql.SQLException: Closed Statement: next`

The table is like follows:

FNAME LNAME ADDR MAIL OCCU UNAME PASSWD 
aaa    aaa  aaaa aaa  aaaa   bbb cccc 
bkgkb jjv jhvjmh jjkg jvjv jvjvh bjbmb

Please help me resolving this!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `con.commit` line, there is no need for that.

You should add `finally` to your `catch` and close the statement there.

And you should also use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead of Statement.

About `finally` see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html).

Answer (score 1):

First there is no need to use

```
con.commit();
```

It you can use only in case, if you will set AutoCommit to false.

```
con.setAutoCommit(false);
```

Second, i recommend to you use `PreparedStatements` which are more faster and safer.

Next, there is no need to close your Statement.

In **finally** block you have to call `con.close()` when you close connection, statement will be closed automatic.

**Note:** You have to call it in finally block, because your `Application` may crash and then your `Connection` never be closed.

```
finally {
   if (con != null) {
      con.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But when I try to write the above mentioned code Eclipse is giving error that It cannot identify con.So what should I do?

Comment: you need to create Connection variable outside of try block so Connection con = null; try { ... }